# How to flatten list in Spark reduceByKey

Tags: pyspark

I am trying to simplify the following code:

```
k=sc.parallelize(["dog", "cat", 'ant']).map(lambda x: (len(x),x))
k.reduceByKey(lambda acc,x: [acc,x]).collect()
```

It is not clear to me why the following fails

```
k.reduceByKey(lambda acc,x: [x] if acc == None else acc.append(x) ).collect()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `groupByKey`:

```
k.groupByKey().mapValues(lambda x: list(x)).collect()
# [(3, ['dog', 'cat', 'ant'])]
```

---

It seems you confused the `reduceByKey` with the `fold` method, which accepts an initial value.

For [`reduceByKey`](http://backtobazics.com/big-data/spark/apache-spark-reducebykey-example/):

> It accepts a Commutative and Associative function as an argument:
>
> - The parameter function should have two arguments of the same data type
> - The return type of the function also must be same as argument types

In your *lambda* function, `acc.append(x)` for instance returns None.

So if using `reduceByKey`, you can do:

```
k.reduceByKey(lambda a, b: (a if isinstance(a, list) else [a]) + (b if isinstance(b, list) else [b])).collect()
# [(3, ['dog', 'cat', 'ant'])]
```